# C#: how to collect service only for certain process name by using ServiceController.GetServices()

Tags: c#

I am able to get all the process using Process.GetProcesses() under "System.Diagnostics" namespace.

Is there any way to get all the service name within certain process by using "ServiceController.GetServices()"?

```
foreach (var theProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if(theProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper() == "SVCHOST")
                {
                    ServiceController.GetServices().Where(e=>e.)
                }

                //Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theProcess.ProcessName, theProcess.Id);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is no way because you have no special *attributes* or *properties*. But you can do the same thing using `ManagementObjectSearcher`

```
foreach (var theProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (theProcess.ProcessName.ToUpper() == "SVCHOST")
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service " + "where ProcessId={0}", theProcess.Id));
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + mo["Name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I know this. Just I wanted to eliminate WMI